# ..level.. in ggplot2 contour plot

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I find this variable a little confusing, for example, from the docs:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
volcano3d <- melt(volcano) 
names(volcano3d) <- c("x", "y", "z") 
v <- ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z)) 
v1 = v +  stat_contour(aes(colour=..level..,size=..level..))
```

Why can't I use this:

```
v2 = v +  stat_contour(aes(colour=as.factor(z),size=as.factor(z)))
```

Answer (score 7):

From Hadley Wickham's [A Layered Grammar of Graphics](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/layered-grammar.pdf), page 21, the `.. ..` is used because the aesthetic (in this case, the levels of the contours) is not present in the original dataset, but instead is calculated by the contour statistic.

> The two dots are a visual indicator highlighting that variable is not present in the original data, but has been computed by the statistic.

You can't use `colour=as.factor(z)` or `size=as.factor(z)` because the graphic doesn't use `z`, but instead uses a statistical transformation of it - namely, `..level..`