# Manually setting scale_alpha for stat_density2d plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, ggmap, kernel-density

I want to plot monthly maps of local construction specifically using `stat_density2d` from ggplot2. I am using the following code:

```
library(ggmap)
options(stringsAsFactors=T)

mar_2016 <- structure(list(Latitude = c(47.6064785, 47.6086266, 47.61556306,
                                        47.5335102, 47.53424442, 47.62629031, 47.66231885, 47.55882248,
                                        47.63847192, 47.63847192, 47.63847192, 47.63846822, 47.66045328,
                                        47.64787497, 47.6774562, 47.61126358, 47.61126358, 47.62041964,
                                        47.56586818, 47.56600353), Longitude = c(-122.3313647, -122.32373921,
                                                                                 -122.33276181, -122.3473748, -122.29267751, -122.32268625, -122.28147251,
                                                                                 -122.36343703, -122.36995433, -122.36995433, -122.36995433, -122.36979987,
                                                                                 -122.30463329, -122.37841989, -122.31846715, -122.31515559, -122.31515559,
                                                                                 -122.35567747, -122.3694264, -122.36942834)), .Names = c("Latitude",
                                                                                                                                          "Longitude"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

apr_2016 <- structure(list(Latitude = c(47.62373953, 47.61304116, 47.57543057,
                                        47.59216, 47.66411106, 47.71560842, 47.55499461, 47.55878986,
                                        47.5224678, 47.5224678, 47.63419063, 47.70380892, 47.6309837,
                                        47.60766995, 47.52517771, 47.68700879, 47.68495153, 47.6733502,
                                        47.61578904, 47.66961751, 47.62981265, 47.62126347, 47.60219778,
                                        47.6086266, 47.52835462, 47.67514813, 47.67514813, 47.66513236,
                                        47.56720557, 47.66590858), Longitude = c(-122.30442288, -122.34060091,
                                                                                 -122.39628552, -122.29016643, -122.34337082, -122.31338271, -122.38583914,
                                                                                 -122.26472731, -122.35949442, -122.35949442, -122.35408737, -122.37250127,
                                                                                 -122.3076156, -122.32802388, -122.36489489, -122.38298825, -122.36237138,
                                                                                 -122.35121936, -122.33727143, -122.36591715, -122.29125798, -122.32173169,
                                                                                 -122.33348074, -122.32373921, -122.39195911, -122.28949534, -122.28949534,
                                                                                 -122.28937395, -122.39185006, -122.2962011)), .Names = c("Latitude",
                                                                                                                                          "Longitude"), row.names = c(412L, 416L, 417L, 426L, 427L, 428L,
                                                                                                                                                                      429L, 434L, 437L, 438L, 454L, 456L, 475L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L,
                                                                                                                                                                      493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 507L, 510L, 516L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L,
                                                                                                                                                                      529L, 541L), class = "data.frame")


denny_park = get_map(location=c(-122.3437739, 47.6193031), zoom=15)
ggmap(denny_park) +
  geom_density2d(data = apr_2016, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 0.3) +
  stat_density2d(data = apr_2016,
                 aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01,
                 bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("April 2016")

ggmap(denny_park) +
  geom_density2d(data = mar_2016, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 0.3) +
  stat_density2d(data = mar_2016,
                 aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01,
                 bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE) +
  ggtitle("March 2016")
```

which produces [image] and [image]

How can I manually set the `stat_density()` fill parameter to give the same legend for both plots? According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688649/level-in-ggplot2-contour-plot), the `..level..` parameter is calculated by calling `MASS::kde2d`. Manually calling this gives a list:

```
R> apr_2016_kde <- MASS::kde2d(apr_2016$Longitude, apr_2016$Latitude)
R> str(apr_2016_kde)
List of 3
 $ x: num [1:25] -122 -122 -122 -122 -122 ...
 $ y: num [1:25] 47.5 47.5 47.5 47.5 47.6 ...
 $ z: num [1:25, 1:25] 23.2 27 30.2 32.7 34.2 ...
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845652/specifying-the-scale-for-the-density-in-ggplot2s-stat-density2d) is pretty close, but complains about Error: Unknown parameters: breaks for `stat_density2d()` in ggplot2 version 2.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the same `limits` argument to `scale_fill_gradient` in both plots. For example, `scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red", limits=c(0,70000))` (or whatever range you wish). Then the same colors will be mapped to the same values in each plot.

Here's what the plots look like with the limits I added:

[image]

(Note: The title of your question mentions scale_alpha, but the body of your question asks how to get the same fill legend. I've assumed you want the same fill legend in each plot, but please let me know if you wanted something different.)

Comment: Nice, yeah seems like me focusing on scale_alpha was a signal that I was tired and way out on the weeds on this one. Thanks!